NO tekton task , taskrun or pipeline working in tekton
    # hello-world.yaml
    apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
    kind: Task
    metadata:
      name: hello
    spec:
      steps:
        - name: echo
          image: alpine
          script: |
            #!/bin/sh
            echo "Hello World"
    
    # hello-world-run.yaml
    apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
    kind: TaskRun
    metadata:
      name: hello-task-run
    spec:
      taskRef:
        name: hello
      timeout: "1h0m0s" # 1 hour timeout

kubectl get taskrun hello-task-run
NAME             SUCCEEDED   REASON           STARTTIME   COMPLETIONTIME hello-task-run   False       TaskRunTimeout   138m        78m

TaskRun "hello-task-run" failed to finish within "1h0m0s"


Please help me
Expected according to tekton docs

You need to look in the pod logs and events when you start the task. Most probably you cannot pull the image for the task.
